# NSight skipping breakpoints while debugging

Tags: debugging, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nsight

I have a cuda application which I am trying to debug using parallel Nsight debugger. I have a breakpoint in my kernel function. But when I am trying to debug the code the debugger is not stopping at the breakpoint and  printing out the result straight away. I have searched about this and I also got a post like [this one](http://postimg.org/image/fjd2873bn/).
But I have checked "Generate GPU Debug Information" in the property page of my project and it is already turned to "Yes (-G0)". I have also set breakpoints in one of the Nvidia sample program like matrixMulCUDA and I can easily debug their program and able to see the details. So I don't know exactly what I should do or what other settings I need to change so that I could debug my program. There are few more information I would like to provide : 
1. I am using Microsoft visual studio 2010
2. My GPU card is NVidia 560ti.
3 I am using CUDA 5.0 and parallel NSight visual studio version 2.2.

Here are some screenshots of the the [host code function](http://postimg.org/image/fjd2873bn/) from where I am calling the kernel and also a portion of the [kernel function](http://postimg.org/image/rjx4ytesx/) where I have set the breakpoint. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One possibility is that your kernel is not executing at all.  Are you doing [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)?  I don't see any in the host code picture you provided.  You might also try running your code with `cuda-memcheck` to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: No, you are right. I haven't done a proper cuda error checking. But there is one thing.The result I am getting from the printf after copying back the matrix to the cpu, I am getting a desired result. So I believe that the kernel is executing. But still I will do as you have suggested and I will let you know. But could there be any other viable reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: HI!
I just tested my kernel using cudaGetLastError()(somewhat mentioned in this website: http://www.visualization.hpc.mil/wiki/Handling_CUDA_error_messages) and the kernel is executing without any error. So what else is to be done to perform the debugging?

Comment: Just wondering where did you set the brsakpount? Is that instruction executed by a thread?

Comment: HI!
I have set the breakpoint where the thread id is getting evaluated as shown in the kernel image that I have uploaded.

Comment: When you do a clean build, do you see the kernel files being compiled with the -G debugging flag? If not, right click on the files containing your CUDA kernels, and click Properties. Expand the CUDA C/C++ tree, and select Device. Ensure you have selected Yes (-G) for the Generate GPU Debug Information option.

Also, I recommend upgrading to Nsight 3.0 RC2. It is a free download available from the Nsight Registered Developer Program.

Comment: @JeffDavis

Hi!

Thank you for your reply. But my GPU debug information is already turned to "Yes-G"and as I have mentioned that I have done a kernel error check and my kernel is also running without any error. Though I can upgrade to the latest version but my only concern is that I am able to debug the other sample codes without any problem.

Comment: @JeffDavis 

Hi! Thanks for the suggestion of upgrading the Nsight version. That worked and now I am able to hit the breakpoint. So I think now I can debug. It would be helpful if you could post this as answer and I will accept it. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've fixed many bugs such as these in NVIDIA Nsight 3.0 RC2. I recommend all users upgrade to to NVIDIA Nsight 3.0 as soon as possible. It is a free download available from the [Nsight Registered Developers Program](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition-registered-developer-program).